# Editor template null reference exception for model subclass Items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I am using an Editor template for loading an enumerator and code is like

```
@model Enum
@{
    // Looks for a [Display(Name="Some Name")] Attribute on your enum
    Func<Enum, string> getDescription = en =>
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {

            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute),
            false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
        }

        return en.ToString();
    };
    var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
    new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = getDescription(e),
        Value = e.ToString(),
        Selected = e.Equals(Model)
    });

    @Html.DropDownList("", listItems, new {@class="form-control" })
}
```

In my Razor view i have a model with 2 properties

@model RoyaltyDb.Models.LicenseItemModel

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemMain, "Enum_DropdownList", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubClassModel.ItemSub, "Enum_DropdownList", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on the line

```
var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select(e =>
    new SelectListItem()
    {
```

But no issue for the first line ie main property of model .
This is my enumerator and ItemMain and ItemSub are of type CurrencyEnums

```
       public enum CurrencyEnums
    {
        [Display(Name = "Nk")]
        Nk,
        [Display(Name = "Dollas")]
        Dolar,
        [Display(Name = "EURO")]
        EUR
    }
```

Any idea why i am getting null exception for subclass property?

Comment: In MVC5, there is a `EnumDropDownListFor` helper method. No need to hassle with creating SelectListItems. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776908/Dealing-with-Enum-in-MVC